# How do I join the Dark Brotherhood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Oblivion, you simply have to kill 2 or three people and then are contacted by the Dark Brotherhood in your sleep. In Skyrim, I have killed lots of people, but I can't seem to find the Dark Brotherhood and I haven't been contacted. Is there a different way you join in Skyrim?

Comment: In Oblivion, you only have to kill one person.  I found that out due to an errant fireball during a fighter's guild quest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Yahoo! Answers post, "How do i join the dark brotherhood in skyrim?":](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111115131904AAKU1nX)

> While on your travels in Skyrim, go to any inn and ask for the latest
>   gossip. The innkeeper will tell you that there is a child trying to
>   perform the Black Sacrement in Windhelm. If you happen to be in
>   Riften, speak to a man named Maul. He will be standing against a post
>   as soon as you enter the city. After sharing some tough words with
>   you, he gives you information on both the Thieves Guild, and the Dark
>   Brotherhood; for a price, of course. You could alternatively talk to
>   Idesa Sadri inside Candalhearth Hall in Windhelm and ask about a
>   cursed child performing the Black Sacrement. Idesa can also be
>   overheard talking to Grimvar Cruel-Sea about the child, Aventus
>   Aretino, outside the Aretino Residence. Aventus Aretino can be found
>   inside the Aretino Residence, which has a novice-level lock. The child
>   will offer you the Innocence Lost quest, which will lead to the quest
>   With Friends Like These....
>
> After Innocence Lost has been completed, a courier will appear and
>   give you a note with the imprint of a black hand and the words "We
>   Know" written beneath it. If you do not receive the note, wait for a
>   couple of days. Once you receive the note, sleep in any bed.
>   Thereafter, you are abducted by the Dark Brotherhood, taken to an
>   Abandoned Shack, and asked to kill one of three people in the room
>   (With Friends Like These... ). Killing one or all of the potential
>   victims will earn you an invitation to join the Dark Brotherhood. You
>   may also take the opportunity to destroy the organization by attacking
>   the Dark Brotherhood representative, Astrid. This will initiate the
>   quest Destroy the Dark Brotherhood!.

Comment: [Please don't take answers from other locations without citing the source.](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111115131904AAKU1nX) We do not support plagiarism.

Comment: I'm new to the site and didn't realize this. Sorry

Comment: My apologies if I sounded harsh. I've edited your post to make it fit with our standards for citing sources. The above is a "block quote", which is what we use when taking a large section of text from a source. Also, welcome to our site :)

Comment: @Wipqozn The "Yahoo! Answers" link to [hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) doesn't seem to link to Hunter's source. (can't find any info there about the Dark Brotherhood or a Yahoo! Answers link). I edited the link in the question to lead to the [link in your comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38641/how-do-i-join-the-dark-brotherhood#comment55944_38642).

Answer (score 5):

Complete the quests [Innocence Lost](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Innocence_Lost) and [With Friends Like These...](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/With_Friends_Like_These...) to be invited to the Dark Brotherhood.

Speak to Aventus Arentino in the Arentino residence in Windhelm to begin the quest line.